# My parameters on my main report won't add to my subreport in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have done this before, where the main report's parameters are passed on to the subreport. Currently, there are 2 parameters from the main report being passed to my subreport, but I need to add 2 more. When I go through the "Change Subreport Links" option and select and add the needed parameters, it simply doesn't save. I am not sure how else to add these.

Comment: There must be something corrupt going on. You should be able to add as many links as you want. Why dont you try redoing the report from scratch if thats not a pain. Start with redoing the sub report first. 
Or may be the links you are trying to add are not in any of the tables added to the subreport.

Comment: Normally this should happen without any problem.. try restarting the CR and check as sometimes CR behaves strangly restarting will fix the issue.

Comment: It turned out that it was a datatype mismatch between the two report's parameters. Such an easy fix, but also easy to miss! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

- create desired parameters in sub-report
- create corresponding parameters in main report
- link with 'linking expert'

Answer (score 0):

The datatypes of the parameters fields did not match, so the two were not correlating.